# How to reduce the queue time in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I am currently looking for strategies to reduce queue time in Apache Airflow. On average, my DAGs take about 10 to 15 minutes to complete their tasks, out of which approximately 6 minutes are spent in the queue. I manage around 40 DAGs, all of which run on an hourly schedule. Any advice or tips on optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated.

I did try updating to new version and cleaning up the database (I'm keeping only 7 days worth of logs and instances so I don't think its database problem) I'm using pgbouncer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Long queue time is based on amount of active tasks, cleaning the meta database or updating versions will have minimal affects on queue time.

Basically to decrease queue time you need to handle the task load more efficiently. This could be allocating additional workers so more tasks can run concurrently, or staggering the schedule out so not as many tasks run at one time. We have a high task volume deployment and we run our DAGs on two blocks, on the hour and half hour or quarter after and quarter before. If possible I would recommend the scheduling route as its cost effective.

Additionally, check to make sure you are not limiting your DAGs needlessly. Airflow provides several methods to effectively rate limit DAGs such as Pools and configurations of the DAG and tasks themselves. This could cause tasks to queue waiting for an open slot to run.